# how to calculate the Resistor for a mosfet so that the Vout 10 V is?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis

These value are given:

- VDD = 15V
- Zener voltage = 6.8V
- Zener current = 5mA
- Rs = 3kOhm

[image]
here is the link to the data sheet:
https://nl.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/supertex_2n7000-1181251.pdf

I have calculated that R1 most be (15-6.8)/5mA =1.6kOhm but I'm stuck there.

Comment: The \$V_{DS}\$ of your M1 should be negliglible so in a first approximation \$V_{A}\$ will be \$V_{RS}\$.

Comment: Look up the **threshold voltage** of the 2N7000. You know the voltage at the gate (6.2 V) so you can determine the voltage across \$R_S\$, you know \$R_S\$ is 3 kohm so you can calculate the current through it. Now check if the 2N7000 needs a large \$V_{GS}\$ to conduct that current, is that \$V_{GS}\$ larger than the threshold voltage? (my guess: it is not but check anyway). You know \$I_D\$ and the voltage across \$R_D\$ + D1, the rest is easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s one way to go about solving for the last unknown resistor R<sub>D</sub>. Because you’re using a MOSFET to create a dc voltage of 10V on drain pin, I’m going make the assumption that the MOSFET will be operating in saturation mode and thus has a drain to source voltage V<sub>DS</sub>>1V. Now, for it to operate in saturation mode, the gate to source voltage  V<sub>GS</sub> must be greater than the gate threshold voltage V<sub>GSth</sub>. From your datasheet, this is at minimum 0.8V and Max 3V. Let’s go with 0.8V here as first try. We want  V<sub>GS</sub>>0.8V but also not too large because then we might enter into ohmic region which isn’t what we want. Well let’s see if datasheet can provide more info. If we take a look at the transfer characteristic curve, if we have V<sub>GS</sub>=2V, we have transistor on, and some current flow. See figure below with marked red lines. This is a start. Now let’s try to find R<sub>D</sub>. If V<sub>GS</sub>=2V and V<sub>G</sub>=6.8V, then V<sub>S</sub>=4.8V. Then I<sub>S</sub>= I<sub>D</sub> =4.8V/3kohm=1.6mA. Now if V<sub>A</sub>= V<sub>D</sub>=10V then V<sub>RD</sub>=15V-0.7V-10V=4.3V. Finally, R<sub>D</sub>=4.3V/1.6mA=2687 ohm. We can approximate this as 2.7 kohm. If you simulate this circuit with values found, (I have already), you’ll find that V<sub>A</sub>=10.22V. No bad for first try. If you try again with an adjustment to V<sub>GS</sub>, you’ll eventually find that R<sub>D</sub>=2.8kohm will give much better result.
[image]

[image]